# How to update user control values?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, oracle10g

I want to update user control values

I tried but values are overwriting

Table:

```
ID    EmpID   VisaNumb  VisaType   VisaEntry  ExpiryDate

1      73      1234     Student     Single    20-Oct-2013
2      73      7654     Business    Multiple  25-Oct-2013
```

Code:

```
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  foreach (var control in rpt1.Controls)
  {
    var usercontrol = control as VisaUserControl;
    string visaNumber = usercontrol.TextVisaNumber;
    string countryName = usercontrol.VisaCountry;
    string visaType = usercontrol.VisaType;
    string visaEntry = usercontrol.VisaEntry;
    string expirtyVisa = usercontrol.ExpiryDate;

    OleDbCommand visaupdate = new OleDbCommand("Update visa_details set visa_number='" + visaNumber + "',visa_country='" + countryName + "',type_of_visa='" + visaType + "',type_of_entry='" + visaEntry + "',visa_expiry_date='" + expirtyVisa + "' where emp_id = '" + Session["Empid"].ToString() + "'", DbConnection);
    visaupdate.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
```

Table values are overwriting here like

```
ID    EmpID   VisaNumb  VisaType   VisaEntry  ExpiryDate

1      73      7654     Business    Multiple  25-Oct-2013
```

I think If I use (ID field) it will be working but don't know how to use

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: then why dont you store the 'ID' and use it on where clause

Comment: In user controls I don't need ID then how can I get that ID?

Comment: get the ID just the way you get the other values?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response I'm working on it

Comment: Use the ID Along with the EmpID. (ex. where ID=1 **AND** EmpID=73), the reason it's overwriting is because both rows has the EmpID of 73. Also look into the structure of your sql statement [at this link.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx) the way you are doing it now makes it more open to sql injection.